# How to Sort array of objects by a property value

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an array of objects like this. I am trying to sort the array if the holidays have the same holiday_on, and Sort by holiday_for By Descending Order.

```
const holidays: IHoliday[] = [
    {
        id: 1,
        holiday_for: 1,
        holiday_on: "2021-10-26"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        holiday_for: 3,
        holiday_on: "2021-10-26"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        holiday_for: 1,
        holiday_on: "2021-11-26"
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        holiday_for: 3,
        holiday_on: "2021-11-26"
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        holiday_for: 4,
        holiday_on: "2021-11-26"
    }
]
```

With the implementation below getting this type error `Argument of type '(a: IHoliday, b: IHoliday) => number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type '(a: IHoliday, b: IHoliday) => number'.Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'`

If I make the holidays array any type then typescript giving another warning - `Not all code paths return a value.`

**Implementation**

```
const sorted = holidays.sort((a: IHoliday, b: IHoliday) => {
    if (a.holiday_on === b.holiday_on) {
        return b.holiday_for - a.holiday_for;
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: I would suggest to use a library underscore or lodash both the libraries  have lot of inbuilt utilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added another return so that if the holiday_on is not the same, it will sort the date but you cannot directly make an operation with the type Date in Typescript. Using getTime() method converts a Date into a number (Date.prototype.getTime()) so you can make the operation without error.

```
const sorted = this.holidays.sort((a: IHoliday, b: IHoliday) => {
  if (a.holiday_on === b.holiday_on) {
    return b.holiday_for - a.holiday_for;
  }
  return (
    new Date(b.holiday_on).getTime() - new Date(a.holiday_on).getTime()
  );
});
console.log(sorted);
```

I added a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fehqdh?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for you to play on.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort function needs to always return a number. `0` if equal, `>=1` if greater, and `<=-1` if smaller.

```
const sorted = holidays.sort((a: IHoliday, b: IHoliday) => {
    if (a.holiday_on === b.holiday_on) {
        return b.holiday_for - a.holiday_for;
    }
    return new Date(b.holiday_on) - new Date(a.holiday_on)
});
```

This function will attempt to sort by `holiday_on` first, and only if it's equal, then it sorts by `holiday_for`.

Comment: In the second return where you have added `new Date` getting this error - `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.`

Comment: Code should work if you ignore the error, but to be more specific you can use `return new Date(b.holiday_on).getTime() - new Date(a.holiday_on).getTime()`